# Show that the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2y^4}{x^4+y^8} ,& \text{if } (x,y)≠ (0,0) \\ 0, &\text{if } (x,y)= (0,0)\end{cases}$ is Gateaux

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Show that the function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2y^4}{x^4+y^8} ,& \text{if } (x,y)≠ (0,0) \\ 0, &\text{if } (x,y)= (0,0)\end{cases}$$

is Gateaux differentiable at $(0,0)$ but not continuous at $(0,0)$.

So I know how to show it is Gateaux differentiable at $(0,0)$, but I don't know how to go about showing it is not continuous...

Comment: Do you know the definition of the Gateaux derivative?

Comment: I know the definition of Gateaux -> f is Gateaux differentiable at a in R^n if lim [f(a+tv)-f(a)]/t is the dot product of L and v. But not for the derivative...

Answer (score 0):

Let $v = (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$. We have:

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f((0,0) + tv) - f(0,0)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(tx,ty)}t = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{ \large \frac{t^6x^2y^4}{t^4(x^4 + t^4y^8)}}t = \lim_{t \to 0}t \frac{x^2y^4}{x^5 + t^4y^8} = 0$$

Then, $f$ is Gateaux differentiable at $(0,0)$ with its differential being $0$.

To show that $f$ is not continuous, we consider the two paths: $y=x$ and $y = \sqrt x$:

$$\lim_{\large \begin{cases} (x,y) \to (0,0) \\ y = x \end{cases}} f(x,y) = 0$$

But:

$$\lim_{\large \begin{cases} (x,y) \to (0,0) \\ y = \sqrt x \end{cases}} f(x,y) = \frac12 $$